# Does PHP have an inverse of the date() function (other than strtotime())?

Tags: php, date

Is there a function that uses the `date()` format to interpret a string?

```
echo date('s-i-H d:m:Y', 1304591364); // 34-29-17 05:05:2011

// Does this function exist?
echo inverse_date('s-i-H d:m:Y', '34-29-17 05:05:2011'); // 1304591364
```

I know `strtotime()`, but it’s failing me in most cases as I am not parsing English date formats.

I’m looking for a function that can dictate the format.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The real answer to this question the way I mean it is
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```php
    $date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'); // 2009-02-15
```

Comment: Only in PHP 5.3, unfortunately.

Comment: Alternative syntax: `$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $var)`

Answer (score 9):

You would typically use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for that:

```
echo strtotime('2011-05-05 17:29:34');
```

From the manual:

> strtotime — Parse about any English
>   textual datetime description into a
>   Unix timestamp

See [valid date and time formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) to be sure that the string you are passing in will be parsed correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I used strtotime, but as I am not based in the US, I need to control the formats

Answer (score 4):

PHP 5.4+ will print 1359674625

```
echo date_create_from_format('j/n/Y G:i:s','1/2/2013 1:23:45')->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: This is the actual correct way to do it, i.e. using the DateTime object

Answer (score 1):

The function `mktime` seems to do what you want.

Check the help over at php.net:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

EDIT : indeed `strtotime` may be more convenient for you, I did not know that function, glad to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is right IMO, but you can also use the OO syntax: `DateTime::createFromFormat` eg:

```
$dateTimeObject = \DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', '9:30');
$dateTimeObject->format('H:i');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for formatting guides, and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php for info on the method described above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use:

```
echo strtotime("2011-05-05 17:29:34");
```

Comment: see edit, I'm looking for the function that can dictate the format

Comment: you can use regex to validate format of your date.
something like this /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reverse:

$x = '2013-09-15';

$x = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('-', $x)));

// now $x = '15-09-2013'

Comment: nice, however I didn't mean I wanted to reverse the order :)