# datetime to timestamp

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Inverse date function? - not strtotime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895519/inverse-date-function-not-strtotime)
>   [Is it possible to get UNIX time from such date 2011-02-27 02:04:46?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749319/is-it-possible-to-get-unix-time-from-such-date-2011-02-27-020446)

hello,

we have this function to convert a timestamp to datetime:

```php
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

is there a function to do the opposite?

datetime to timestamp.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get UNIX time from such date 2011-02-27 02:04:46?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5749319)

Comment: Nope, you must parse it and use `mktime`.

Comment: This function converts the timestamp to a date, you wrote the opposite.

Comment: question shows no research effort whatsoever

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
```

Or if you're confident of the format, split up the string with `explode()` or even `substr` and pass the necessary parts into the `mktime` function.

Be aware that `strtotime` can sometimes get the timestamp wrong, if a slightly unconventional format is used.

## EDIT:

A really accurate way of doing this is if you know your input format, is to use `DateTime::createFromFormat` eg:

```
$dateTimeObject = \DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', '9:30');
$dateTimeObject->format('H:i');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for formatting guides, and http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php for info on the method described above.

Comment: Is there a certain format that `strtotime` will always get right?

Comment: @Shoelaced generally if you use well formatted YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS TZ it will work.

Comment: This answer has 69 Upvotes and I feel I don't want to spoil that.
https://prnt.sc/jr6zBoMk1Xk8

Answer (score 8):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('12-04-2010');
```