# Convert date time to timestamp using php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I am quite sure this has been discussed before but for some reason mine is not working.

I am trying to convert date time to a timestamp.

```
echo strtotime("18 May 2.50pm");
```

The above code returns blank.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `18 May` of which year ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225216/datetime-to-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Use php [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to make DateTime

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j M h.ia', '18 May 2.50pm');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
//print_r($date);
?>
```

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/1006942)

Now you can use method available for DateTime .

**Note** : As you have not given year it will give you result for current year